# Byte array of 13 MB gives out of memory exception in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, arrays, memory, byte, allocation

I have an application which converts HTML to PDF by converting it into a byte array. However, what I observe, as my byte array size exceeds **13 MB**, it gives: `OutOfMemoryException`

As far as I know, I can have a max of 2GB allocated to variables in my 32-bit machine and I also dispose other variables used. Then ideally I should not fall short on memory, isnt it?

Plus, when i declare the byte array size initially as **1 gb**, it doesn't give an error but when it is assigned with data, the size of the array **resizes** as per the size of the data and when it exceeds **13 gb**, it crashes?

Why does the array **resizes** when i have already declared it to hold **1gb** memory?

****EDIT:**

Following are my lines of code which causes the error:

```
objpage.Layout(html1); //html1 holds my huge full HTML which is of approx 5.5k word doc                 //pages 

pdfBuffer = new byte[1073741824]; //declare the byte array of size 1 gb,no error here.  //Note, i just added this declaration, this is not the cause of the problem, it wasn't //initially there 

pdfBuffer = document1.WriteToMemory(); //This is my API method of the third party tool  //which converts pdf document object to byte array. This line is where the error comes (my //array of 1 GB gets resized to 13+ MB)
```

Comment: what kind of exeception?

Comment: It gives "OutOfMemoryException"

Comment: show us some of your code. its hard to debug with out seeing something.

Comment: A web application is normally limited to 300 MB. If you grow the array, it needs to allocate a new copy, so you can't grow an array to more than 150 MB. As the application is already using some memory for other things, it's even less than that. It would help to see the code where you get the exception.

Comment: Its difficult to put the code here as it is huge and a code block won't be of any use since my HTML string goes to around 5500 word file pages which i convert into a PDF document using third party (HIQPDF) tool. One of the methods in this tool then converts the whole document into a byte array as follows:

Comment: EDIT THE question itself and include the CODES!

Comment: edited the ques and included the code block @AsshO.Le . kindly have a look into it

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem like this before,

i tried editing some codes in the `webconfig` file and this is what worked for me.

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="100" maxRequestLength="819200" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"/>
</system.web>
```

have you tried editing the execution time out and max request length? try changing it and giving it a higher number.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but my current paramaters are already holding a higher value. Following is my current web.config entry:

Comment: <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0"  maxRequestLength="1048576"  executionTimeout="180"/>

Comment: You need to up the max for IIS as well as the application.

Comment: My code is not working on my local machine too, so there is no question of IIS settings for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
 <system.web>
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000000" executionTimeout="99999999"/>
 <pages validateRequest="false"/>
 </system.web>
```

here increase the values according to your application